# How to regroup NSMutableArray on tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsarray

This is how I regroup the array in viewDidLoad :

```
arrayChild=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
arrayTitle=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
arrayParent=[CM getParentCategory];
for (int i=0; i<arrayParent.count; i++) {
    c=[[POI_Category alloc]init];
    c=[arrayParent objectAtIndex:i];
    [arrayTitle addObject:c.name];
    [arrayChild addObject:[CM getChildCategory:c._id]];
}
```

and in the cellForRow :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"categoryCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
@try {
   POI_Category *category=[[POI_Category alloc]init];
    category=[[arrayChild objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:category.name]; //This line always get EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x10)
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"exc:%@",exception);
}


return cell;
}
```

so why with the bad access? Did i use the category in a wrong way?

Comment: So I guess `-getParentCategory` returns an `NSArray` of `POI_Category` objects. What does `-getChildCategory:` do?

Comment: @stefandouganhyde, well it's my stupid mistake, found property (nonatomic,assign) NSString* name; when it should be retain :) thanks for your help!

Comment: Good stuff, @xeravim. One thing to note, there are a couple of points in your example code where you declare a `POI_Category` pointer and `alloc` and `init` a new instance. Then you assign an object from an array to your pointer, so the new instance is released by ARC. Essentially, you don't need the `[[POI_Category alloc] init` bits.